# Managing hidden Backbone views that share the same model with a visible view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

We've been using Backbone for several months, but we think there must be a better way of dealing with hidden views when they share a model with a visible view. For instance, we have a "View Segment" view and an "Edit Segment" view both representing a "Segment" model. One of these is always hidden at any given moment, however, still listening to the same events as the other (including ajax calls). The reasoning behind why we are just hiding the view vs replacing is that we want to minimize the load time between the changing views since the views display a great deal of data and dom elements. We are thinking that the hidden view doesn't have to be rendered until it is made visible.

Is there a proper (best practice) way of handling this scenario? How would you handle this problem? Is there a simple way to temporarily disable event listening for an entire view?

Comment: update: I should have clarified that I also wanted to turn off the listening of events triggered by model changes.

Answer (score 6):

We use the exact same scenario with display and edit views. We have collected all model binding logic into a `bindEvents` method and complemented it with an `unbindEvents` method.

In the `hide`-method of the view, we call `unbindEvents` and in the `show` method we call the `bindEvents`. Simple as that. We also call the `bindEvents` in the `initialize` method and the `unbindEvents` in the `remove` method to avoid zombie views.

We don't care about javascript events as they typically don't get fired on hidden views (most of the are click or change driven)

By the way, to avoid rendering a bunch of html that will never be shown, we defer the first rendering of the view until it is first shown, so in the `show` method we test `this.isRendered` (a boolean, false by default) and if it is unset, we render the view before showing it and sets it to true.

Answer (score 3):

My views always listen to the change event of a Model, when Model change I render it. I suppose the same for you, so when a Model is fetched(ajax call that you mean) you do not want to anything. In your render(and in your listening method for the model change) you could validate if visible:

```
render : function(){
  if( !this.$el.is(":visible") ){
    //skipping any render action because our view is hidden
    return this;
  }
}
```

And also declare events to work only if the main element of your view is visible, just add in the selector the prefix :visible before any of your child selector:

```
"click :visible .button" : "buttonClickHandler"
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea:
I think you can use the delegateEvents Backbone.Viewt provide, and undelegateEvents method to dynamically set the Events when you want to display **EditSegment** first use undelegateEvents dynamic cancellation **ViewSegment** of Events, then delegateEvents dynamic initialization **EditSegment** the Events.

**EDIT-20120801:about model.unbind**

```
    bindTo: function(model, ev, callback) {
        model.bind(ev, callback, this);
        this.bindings.push({
            model: model,
            ev: ev,
            callback: callback
        });
    },

    _unbindFromAll: function() {
        _.each(this.bindings, function(binding) {
            binding.model.unbind(binding.ev, binding.callback);
        });
        this.bindings = [];
    },
```

Comment: (un)delegateEvents only turns off the event listening for events you define in the view's 'events' object. I want to turn off the listening of model changes.

Comment: @TomoSuzuki hi,see my update,appropriate changes to your requirements can be achieved.